# Add repositories as branches of another repository with all their histories

Tags: git, branch

I have some old repositories that are separate while most of them are actually branches of the main repository.

Is there a way to bring these repositories into the main repository as branches while keeping all of their history?

Comment: You can use git sub repositories, but they won't "become branches".

Comment: Are you referring to submodules?

Comment: I think I am. Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do for each of your old repositories (assuming that those repositories have only one branch `master`):

1. `cd` to your main repo

```sh
cd path/to/mainrepo
```

2. Add the old repo as a remote of the main repo:

```sh
git remote add oldrepo path/to/oldrepo
```

3. Fetch from that new remote:

```sh
git fetch oldrepo
```

4. Create a new branch with what you just fetched:

```sh
git branch oldrepo remotes/oldrepo/master
```

5. After that, of course, it would make sense to delete the remote (particularly if you delete your old repo which is now a new branch—with all its history—of your main repo):

```sh
git remote rm oldrepo
```

If some of your old repos have multiple branches, you have to fetch and create a new branch for each of these branches separately following the exact same method.